# How to turn off "matching" highlighting in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want Visual Studio Code to highlight matching brackets, all occurrences of the same variable, etc.  I find it very distracting.  However, I can find no way to disable this feature.

The only highlight options I seem to be able to change are "editor.selectionHighlight" and "editor.renderLineHighlight", and neither work.

Is it possible to disable "matching highlighting"?  Or maybe to edit my theme, so that the highlight color and highlight border are the same as the background color?

Answer (score 130):

There are different types of highlighting:

#### 1. Syntax highlighting (place cursor inside variable)

[image]

```json
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false
```

#### 2. Selection highlighting (similar chunks in document)

[image]

```json
"editor.selectionHighlight": false
```

#### 3. Matching brackets highlighting

```json
"editor.matchBrackets": false
```

---

There's a second way - make them less obtrusive (or completely transparent):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#0000", // similar selection
    "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#0000",

    "editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground": "#0000", // syntax variable assignment
    "editor.wordHighlightStrongBorder": "#0000",

    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#0000", // syntax variable
    "editor.wordHighlightBorder": "#0000",

    "editorBracketMatch.border": "#0000",// brackets
    "editorBracketMatch.background": "#0000",
}
```

Comment: There's also a double clicking on a word. which one is that ?

Comment: It will highlight both (selection & symbol) on symbol. And only (selection) on non-symbol word.

Comment: **more info based on this answer with even more images, tips!** https://stackoverflow.com/a/63303503/294884

Comment: The first kind of highlighting in image one is called "Occurrences Highlight" and can be modified by `"editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff0000"`. More info can be seen here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors:~:text=editor.selectionHighlightBackground%3A%20Color%20for%20regions%20with%20the%20same%20content%20as%20the%20selection.

Answer (score 11):

Try this one `"editor.matchBrackets": false` in your Preferences - User/Workspace setting

[image: image here]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 10):

"Occurrences Highlight" is the setting you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Try going to Preferences-> User Settings
In the `settings.json` to the right add:

```
"editor.selectionHighlight": false
```

Comment: I actually have that set, for both User and Workspace settings.  It does not seem to turn off brace highlighting or all-other-instances-of-the-current-word highlighting.  Here's my settings.json file for both: // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "editor.renderLineHighlight": false    
}

Comment: Are you sure you are not setting // Controls whether the editor should highlight similar matches to the selection
  "editor.selectionHighlight": true,  in your workspace settings?

Comment: I just double-checked.  Both User and Workspace settings.json files have the same two values set: "editor.selectionHighlight": false, "editor.renderLineHighlight": false.  If selectionHighlight is supposed to control matching-brace highlighting, then maybe I've got something else causing it not to work. And I completely forgot to mention I'm on a Mac, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The same achievement from @Alex's answer could be done from the VSCode settings.

Go to **Preferences** -> **Settings** and there search for **Highlight**.
A lot of option would appear, but the ones useful would be under the **Text Editor** section.
Also, you could decide if change it globally (through the User Settings) or just for that window (Workspace Settings).

Comment: In recent versions of VS code, at least as of ver 1.50, this answer helps. To note that you have the "Workspace" settings tab only if you have saved a workspace.