# How to change the highlights for selected text and selection/word matches in VS Code?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

### Visual confusion: 'selected text' and 'selection matches' highlight color

As a daily VS Code user I found an earlier closed issue ([Selection and selection matches highlight color #1636](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1636)) about this - i.e. if you *actually select* some text it's highlighted, but the highlight colour is all but indistinguishable from the highlight used for matched code or the same word.

### A local user settings-like CSS override?

If the system-wide highlight colour (when selecting *any* text system-wide) isn't portable to VS Code, I need a way to edit it. Perhaps in the theme's CSS or - preferably - in a user-generated 'override css' file or something (like VS Code's user settings). Is this in the pipeline? If not, does anyone have a fix?

ATM changing the highlight colour for selected text appears to be impossible. I'm using 'Dark', but the issue is the same no matter which theme.

Comment: Linking this to a related [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5351) in vscode's github. If this ever gets answered it will start there.

Comment: Here's the actual line in the VSCode code: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/contrib/wordHighlighter/common/wordHighlighter.ts#L120

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was using Night Owl theme by sarah.drasner, for VSCode and by default the text-selection will be overpower by the word-selection, and I get confuse all the time if I really make a selection?.

Testing various variable... the one work for me was the word highlight background (you can try border).

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#0066ff2a",
    "editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground": "#0066ff2a",
}
```

One think I want to clarify you need the 2 values (like rgba) =

1. RGB Color, e.g. [image]

     +
2. Transparency (00 to FF), e.g. **2a**

**BEFORE:**
[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

More info: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors

Comment: PS: `editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground` controls the highlight background color of the other words in the file when you simply have your cursor inside a word. The documentation for it is really really bad, and doesn't state this fact.

Answer (score 46):

To fill-in a couple of missing steps:

1. Open the settings.json file *(see below for location of this file)*
2. Add a comma to the last entry (before the closing brace `}`)
3. Paste-in:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#e788ff", //Current SELECTED text
        "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff0000", //same content as the selection
        "editor.findMatchBackground": "#00cc44a8", //Current SEARCH MATCH
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff7b00a1" //Other SEARCH MATCHES
    }
```

###Example of a typical settings file, post mod:

```
    {
        "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
        "git.autofetch": true,
        "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
        "git.confirmSync": false,
        "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
        "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
        "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
        "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
        "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
        "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
        "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "editor.selectionBackground": "#e788ff7c", //Current selected text
            "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff00005b", //Same content as selection
            "editor.findMatchBackground": "#00cc44a8", //Current SEARCH MATCH
            "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff7b00a1" //Other SEARCH MATCHES
        }
    }
```

---

##Where to find the settings.json file:

```
Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:

Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

##ALTERNATE method to open the settings.json file:

1. `CTRL+SHIFT+P` type `settings.json`, select Preferences: Open **user** settings (JSON)

***or***

1. Ctrl + ,  (comma) to open Settings
2. Workbench
3. Settings Editor
4. In the search box at top, paste-in `workbench.colorCustomizations`
5. On the left, click `Workbench` and then `Appearance`
6. Click the link to right: `Edit in settings.json`

References:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customize-a-color-theme

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: I appreciate the comprehensive answer, the sample complete code with comments and for pinpointing the exact locations of the files.

Comment: To open settings.json: `Ctrl+Shift+P` -> write "settings" -> select "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+P` type `settings.json`, select `Preferences: Open user settings (JSON)`

Answer (score 16):

Now there are many color customizations that can be done to vscode, including the selection options:

```
editor.selectionBackground: Color of the editor selection.
editor.selectionHighlightBackground: Color for regions with the same content as the selection.
editor.inactiveSelectionBackground: Color of the selection in an inactive editor.
```

See [vscode theme color options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference) available from about v1.13 I believe.

Comment: Thanks for that, useful link too. I'm using 1.14.2 - worth pointing out (presumably because set in a theme) that these aren't in "Settings". So you have to add a new `"workbench.colorCustomizations":` block to your user settings.

Answer (score 3):

## The critical answer!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640244/294884

## The settings you want:

these two setting names:

[image]

are these two colors:

[image]

## What is each item?  Huge tip!

There's an incredibly useful mouseover tooltip in the settings.json editor:

Notice it explains at length exactly what the setting does!

[image]

## How to edit these, in current (2020) VSCode ?

One of the joys of VSCode is that preferences are so easy.  (In VS, it is a nightmare.)

Just click Settings, and then just click this:

[image]