# Clicking on a word selects all occurences

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have updated to the latest version of VSCODE and I have this really annoying feature.

If I double click a word, or select the entire word, I am fine.

[image]

The problem is if I just "click" on the text, or am casually going through it with my arrow keys:

It selects every single occurrence in the entire document! How do I get rid of this?

I tried disabling the Editor Selection Highlight feature but this does not fix the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off "matching" highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775406/how-to-turn-off-matching-highlighting)

Comment: "editor.occurrencesHighlight": false; is probably what you want

Comment: Thank you so much mark. After a month I get a useful answer !!