# Multi Selection Words?

Tags: visual-studio-code, multi-select

In VS Code, when I select a word, all equal words in the text are automatically selected. Is it possible to disable this feature? Unfortunately, I don't know what it's called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off "matching" highlighting in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775406/how-to-turn-off-matching-highlighting-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
It's this setting:

`"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false`