Is there a way to remove this reddish highlight on the opening and closing tags that happens on click in VS Code?
I'm trying to disable this reddish highlight in VS Code that happens only in HTML when I click a tag. Upon clicking a tag, the matching opening and closing tags flash this reddish color for a split second. This happens every single time I click most tags in HTML.
I went into my current theme's source code and couldn't find a matching highlight color to the hex code I got from the highlighted tags. I tried to disable the highlight in question by disabling any VS Code extensions I had that could have possibly changed the highlight colors, and went into the settings to adjust colors there. Nothing I tried to disable the reddish highlight worked. The reddish highlight on click still flashes on the tag for a split second every time I click a new tag.

Hey Fredster. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775406/how-to-turn-off-matching-highlighting-in-vs-code
