# Visual Studio Code replacing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just came to know about Visual Studio Code. I would like to know, can I replace Visual Studio for all .NET development related work?
Can I save my cost of Visual Studio licensing?
What is there in Visual Studio which is not there in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the difference between Visual Studio Code and Visual studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-difference-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33798601/2990728) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-Visual-Studio-Code-vs-Visual-Studio-2015-RC).

> The list of differences is huge.
>
> Visual Studio Code is a source code editor developed by Microsoft for Windows, Linux and macOS,
>   with emphasis in just writing the code instead of dealing with
>   debugging, compiling, testing, refactoring, and all the other things
>   that make Visual Studio great.
>
> The people using Visual Studio Code will probably be those on a Mac
>   who will just deal with client-side technologies (HTML/JS/CSS) and do
>   not want to install Windows in order to do that.
>
> People using Windows and developing C#, F# or VB will continue to use
>   Visual Studio 2015.
>
> Also the difference is that .NET has been split into two: .NET Core
>   (Mac/Linux/Windows) .NET Framework (Windows only) All native user
>   interface technologies (Windows Presentation Foundation, Windows
>   Forms, etc) are part of the framework, not the core.
>
> Also, Visual Studio tends to be oriented around Projects & Solutions.
>   Projects have a large amount of scaffolding (pre-generated starting
>   templates) and features.
>
> VS Code looks to be presently oriented around files, as a glorified
>   text editor, and no project scaffolding exists.

Source : MSDN forum and quora

Comment: Visual Studio Code does have debugging capabilities.  I'm debugging python on it as I am typing this.

Comment: "People using Windows and developing C#, F# or VB will continue to use Visual Studio" - yeah, if they can afford it.