# How to Edit multiple lines in Visual studio 2017 at once

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mouse, sublimetext, keyboard-input

I'm following a series of videos on Youtube on [how to develop a dashboard using bootstrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwTr7YHQJfo&list=PLid95FTT3ehi1gtICaGsLfFXGAbVhNg84&index=2). The developer in that series uses the Sublime Text editor.

I've noticed that sometimes he clicks on multiple places (one after another) then start typing, and whatever he's typing appears on all these places. I think that saves a lot of time.

In VS and SSMS, one can press ALT then select a rectangle that will be modified. But this one is different as you can just select randomly several places, then start typing.

Do we have the same functionality in **Visual Studio 2017**?

Comment: Have you tried this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode

Comment: Depends on the project you are coding but if you can use VSCode then that supports multiple insertion points.

Comment: As of the current version, alt+click works!

Comment: There some easy ways:
https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-multi-line-and-multi-cursor-editing.htm

Answer (score 45):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> while left clicking, but that will only be good for multiple lines selection

Answer (score 33):

The question might be dated but in Visual Studio **2019** while holding down

> Ctrl + Alt

click the lines that you want to change and it works as you wanted.

Answer (score 9):

As @besthost and @Noel Nemeth commented, you can use ALT + SHIFT

Another option is keeping ALT pressed and select the lines you want with mouse.

Comment: ALT is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in Visual Studio Code, since it is based on Atom. In VS2017, I believe you can only do `Select+ALT` block editing. I would expect to see features from Code/Atom continue to migrate to VS in the future.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is based on Electron, Atom is also based on Electron. Electron is JS framework that can create an executable out of JS application.

Comment: That's correct, Electron is a JS framework for creating cross-platform desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcuts changes over the versions of VisualStudio.
If any of answers already provided doesn't work for you, you can always check shortcut in Visual Studio options.

Tools -> Environment -> Keyboard

[image: keyboard options]

Answer (score 0):

On mac you can also use `cmd` + `d` + `d` after highlighting certain part of code, and then whatever you type will be reflected to rename in multiple places.

Answer (score -2):

> In  Version 1.26.1 (1.26.1) of Visual Studio code you can edit
>   multiple lines:

```
var donut 1 = "glazed"; 
var donut 2 = "chocolate frosted"; 
var donut 3 = "cinnamon";
```

> go to each location (ie to the right side of the last character ) and
>   hit "Alt" + "spacebar" . It will insert a " | ". When all the lines
>   have a  | (the character above the  backslash) inserted then the cursor > will is controlling all these
>   lines.

////////////// Example One ///////////////////////////

> If we type a , the , will be inserted on all the lines
>   simultaneously.

```
var donut 1 = "glazed";| 
var donut 2 = "chocolate frosted";|
var donut 3 = "cinnamon";|
```

////////////// Example Two ///////////////////////////

> lines. If we hit the backspace key, all three lines will have characters > to the right side of the " |  " will be deleted  on all the lines
>   simultaneously.

```
var donut 1 = |"glazed"; 
var donut 2 = |"chocolate frosted";
var donut 3 = |"cinnamon";
```

> To insert the | character in the line, 
>   position the cursor and  hit "Alt" + "spacebar"

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. The question was about Visual Studio though, not about Visual Studio Code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33798601/5629418

Answer (score -3):

As far as I'm aware you can't. I wanted to find out the same thing a while ago and from what I read online, you can't with Visual Studio. You'll need a plugin that adds extra functionality.

To do this in Sublime Text, you need to press `Ctrl` (Windows) or `Cmd` (Mac) and click to select multiple lines or columns.