# can I set more then one keyboard cursor in Visual Studio like in JetBrains's IDE's?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to set some shortcuts in VS IDE but I used to write code in jetBrains IDE's (e.g. CLion, IJ, PC) which allow to write in several places simultaneously.

is it possible to do the same in VS?

Comment: it does. but i'll leave the question for others and publish this link as an answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @phuzi comment. [How to Edit multiple lines in Visual studio 2017 at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837208/how-to-edit-multiple-lines-in-visual-studio-2017-at-once)
to set more then one keyboard cursor in VS default setting just press Shift+Alt and press several places with left mouse click or just Alt and drag left mouse key to mark rectangle.

you can't edit nons following lines like in CLion for example.