# How do you enable multi-carets editing feature in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, visual-studio-2022

I cannot find the keybinding to do this, I use it very often in VSCode (cmd + D).

For reference of what I'm looking to do:
https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-multi-line-and-multi-cursor-editing.htm#insert-carets-at-all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Edit multiple lines in Visual studio 2017 at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837208/how-to-edit-multiple-lines-in-visual-studio-2017-at-once)

Comment: The link in your post says "If you want to edit multiple places that are unaligned, you can use the multi-cursor edit. Press Ctrl+Alt and click where you want to add a caret"

Answer (score 1):

- `Alt`+`Ctrl`+click: add a caret
- `Alt`+`Shift`+click: directly above caret for a vertical "stack" of carets, or offset to do a block select

`Esc` or click away to cancel