# How to create a model Class with fixed prefix

Tags: c#, .net, model

I have a dotnet core application. I added model class everytime with fixed prefix. It goes very lengthy and unhandled way. Is there any better way to handle this?

```cs
public class Category
{
    public string? gmailIN{ get; set; }

    public string? aolIN{ get; set; }
    public string? outlookIN{ get; set; }
    public string? yahooIN{ get; set; }
    public string? hotmailIN{ get; set; }
    public string? ZohoIN; set; }

    public string? aolAU{ get; set; }
    public string? outlookAU{ get; set; }
    public string? yahooAU{ get; set; }
    public string? hotmailAU{ get; set; }
    public string? ZohoAU{get; set; }
    public string? gmailAU{ get; set; }

    public string? aolUK{ get; set; }
    public string? outlookUK{ get; set; }
    public string? yahooUK{ get; set; }
    public string? hotmailUK{ get; set; }
    public string? ZohoUK{get; set; }
    public string? gmailUK{ get; set; }
        
    public string? gmailUS{ get; set; }
    public string? aolUS{ get; set; }
    public string? outlookUS{ get; set; }
    public string? yahooUS{ get; set; }
    public string? hotmailUS{ get; set; }
    public string? ZohoU{get; set; }
}
```

Prefix is always the same. Is there any better way to add variables instead of adding above way?

Comment: Editing multiple lines at a time will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837208/how-to-edit-multiple-lines-in-visual-studio-2017-at-once

Comment: Do all these properties need to remain in the same class? Does it even need to be properties? Is there a common pattern for determining a property value based on its name? How are you defining "better way"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible split Category and Country.

You can create a class like:

```cs
public class Category
{
   public string? gmail{ get; set; }    
   public string? aol{ get; set; }
   public string? outlook{ get; set; }
   public string? yahoo{ get; set; }
   public string? hotmail{ get; set; }
   public string? Zoho{get; set; }
}
```

and then one Dictionary for mapping it with country

```cs
public Dictionary<string,Category> Categories;
```

or add the Country property inside the Category class itself.