# differentiation between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: c#

I'm confused to choose between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Community 2017. Can someone explain to me in detail? thanks

Comment: Read the product pages and it should become clear what they are and which you should use.

Comment: You can know a few differences in a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio) . I have tried to answer the same, precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Studio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/):
is a Free, fully-featured IDE for students, open-source and individual developers.
It is full featured IDE

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs):
 is a lightweight but powerful source code editor which runs on your desktop and is available for Windows, macOS and Linux.
This is more of like an editor

Answer (score 0):

See the Documentation on both of these Applications

1. [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/vs/overview)
2. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs)

   I fetched a simple description from the documentation

> Visual Studio Code is a lightweight but powerful source code editor
>   which runs on your desktop and is available for Windows, macOS and
>   Linux. It comes with built-in support for JavaScript, TypeScript and
>   Node.js and has a rich ecosystem of extensions for other languages
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE)
>   from Microsoft. It is used to develop computer programs for Microsoft
>   Windows, as well as web sites, web apps, web services and mobile apps.
>   Visual Studio uses Microsoft software development platforms such as
>   Windows API, Windows Forms, Windows Presentation Foundation, Windows
>   Store and Microsoft Silverlight. It can produce both native code and
>   managed code. (Wiki)