# Whats are differences between VS Code and VS 2017 community edition?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

As Microsoft released lots of flavors of VS in recent years, which is confusing to user to choose based on their choice.
I would like to hear form community on below:

VS Code and VS 2017 community edition as both are free and cross platform IDE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code is an Editor which can extended to our needs using plugins while Visual Studio is an IDE.