# Should I install third party tools from the Visual Studio 2017 installer?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I've done a reinstall of Windows and it's finally time for me to move to Visual Studio 2017 and I'm not sure what I should install other than the standard Microsoft workloads.

I'm a bit shocked that the options I selected come to almost 60Gb! Some of the bits like the Android images, I have only needed twice in the past few years - and, I used the Android development kit for them.

I was just wondering, does installing bits from the VS Installer keep them up to date, use the latest versions or have any special integrations? Or, am I best off just installing the Microsoft only core products and then the Android development kit, unity and other bits when I actually need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy to answer. If you ask me I would install Visual Studio 2017 with default options. Then you access / install other components via the `Tools => Get Tools and Features...` menu option. Maybe go to the [Individual Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-5---select-individual-components-optional) view (rather than [the workloads view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-4---select-workloads)) - it features a lot of flexibility in getting individual packages (main article: [Install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio)).

There is also `Tools => Extensions and Options...` to check for upgrades and for third party extensions to Visual Studio. As far as I know these upgrades are not applied automatically.

Finally the `Help => Add and Remove Help Content` allows you to download help content locally (otherwise you go to MDSN for the content each time).

- And there is [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) (cross-platform).

  - [What are the differences between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio)
  - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq
- Download: https://www.visualstudio.com/