# Does VSCode have a different view in mac and in windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am beginner programmer and have just installed VSCode. But to way VSCode looks in the tutorials is different from the one I have.
I mean the Left most and the Topmost looks different.
So I cant flow the tutorial and almost all tutorials has the same look.
The links of the sreenshots are down below:

[image: In the tutorial]

[image: On my VSCode]

Is my version older or it looks like that on windows or anything else, please explain step-by-step cause I am new to this. Thanks a lot!
Sorry if it is a bad Question!

Comment: You downloaded visual studio and not visual studio code ( the image in the bottom is visual studio used for c#..)

Comment: to download vscode https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter Haddad!

Comment: no problem, goodluck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed `Visual Studio` which is a more powerful IDE from Microsoft. Don't confuse it with the editor `Visual Studio Code`.

There is an answer explaining the main differences between the environments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33798601/10770079

> **Visual Studio (full version)** is a "full-featured" and "convenient" development environment.
>
> **Visual Studio (free "Express" versions - only until 2017)** are feature-centered and simplified versions of the full version. Feature-centered meaning that there are different versions (Visual Studio Web Developer, Visual Studio C#, etc.) depending on your goal.
>
> **Visual Studio (free Community edition - since 2015)** is a simplified version of the full version and replaces the separated express editions used before 2015.
>
> **Visual Studio Code (VSCode)** is a cross-platform (Linux, Mac OS, Windows) editor that can be extended with plugins to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded `Visual Studio` **the IDE**.

Visual Studio Code is a pseudo-IDE style text editor.

Be sure you look up **specifically** Visual Studio Code Download for [ insert operating system here ].