# VS2019 linux header files

Tags: c, header-files, visual-studio-2019

I'm experimenting with developing C code for linux using VS2019.

I'm finding that whilst many Linux headers such as sys/types.h and sched.h are being found OK, others, such as sys/syscall.h and fcntl.h are not being found.

I can see that it has a local copy of many headers such as stdint.h in local linux platform directory...can I just cut and paste the missing ones from the target machine?

I rather suspect that if common headers such as unistd.h are missing there is a reason, and I don't want to mess things up!

Comment: Start out by having a look at [What are the differences between Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio)

Answer (score 5):

From [Microsoft's documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=vs-2017)

> By default, Visual Studio does not include any system-level include
>   files from the Linux computer. For example, items in the /usr/include
>   directory are not present in Visual Studio. For full IntelliSense
>   support, you will need to copy those files to some location on your
>   development computer and point Visual Studio to this location. One
>   option is to use scp (Secure Copy) to copy the files. On Windows 10,
>   you can use Bash on Windows to run scp. For previous versions of
>   Windows, you could use something like PSCP (PuTTY Secure Copy).
>
> You can copy the files by using a command similar to the following:
>
> scp -r linux_username@remote_host:/usr/include .
>
> Of course, replace the linux_username and remote_host values above for
>   what's appropriate in your own environment.
>
> Once the files are copied, use the VC++ Directories item in Project
>   properties to tell Visual Studio where to find the additional include
>   files that were just copied.

Comment: Newer versions of Visual Studio will now automatically import remote headers.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=vs-2019#remote_intellisense