# Can Visual Studio Code be installed side by side with visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is it safe to install Visual Studio Code on a machine that has an installation of Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise?

Are there any known issues?

Comment: Yes, its safe. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Of course they can. I have both installed.
To understand the differences better, refer to this answer [What are the differences between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio)

Also, Visual Studio currently (April 2021) works only on Windows and Mac ( separate Visual Studio for MAC), while Visual Studio Code works on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install and use both simultaneously and safely.

Visual Studio Code is a lightweight but powerful source code editor. It has IntelliSense code completion for variables, methods, and imported modules, graphical debugging, linting, multi-cursor editing, parameter hints, and other powerful editing features, and built-in source code control including Git support.
Visual Studio (current version Visual Studio 2019) is Microsoft’s premier IDE. With it, you can develop, debug, analyze, test, collaborate and deploy your software.
Visual Studio doesn’t run on Linux but VS Code does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.
Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two different programs and apart from the name, they haven't too many common points.