# Jupyter Notebook support in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter

I'm able to debug Python programs and would like to use Jupyter Notebboks, but I do not see the Python extension under "Manage Extensions" on VS Professional 2019.

This is a picture of my VS screen. When I search I do not find the pylance or Jupyter extensions.

[image: A VS screen with the extension manager pulled up. The search query is for "pylance" and the result is "No items found for search terms(s): pylance" and nothing else.]

I reviewed the information on [the VSCode page, "Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support), and [the Towards Data Science article, "Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code"](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebook-in-visual-studio-code-3fc21a36fe43).

They show using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the *Command Palette* and this does not do anything in VS Professional or Community 2019. I also tried VS Community 2019 and I'm getting the same results.

I've also watched Jeffrey Mew's video on *[Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSdIoJdSnig)* and Tyreke White's video *[Getting Started with Python in Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EXd4_ttIuw&t=542s)* and it doesn't match what I see in VS.

Is there Jupyter Notebook support in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell... **There is no way to work with Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio that is equivalent to the Visual Studio Code + [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) experience.**

You can, of course, install the [`jupyter`](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/) package in any Python environment (use `pip` or Anaconda) and access the package through the command line. Running `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter lab` in the [Visual Studio command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022) will open the browser interface (so long as the Python environment is active and `jupyter` is correctly installed).

The reason Visual Studio Code has a Jupyter extension and Visual Studio does not is *probably* because Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code serve different purposes. Visual Studio is specifically designed to support .NET and C++ developers. See this quote from the [Visual Studio download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/):

> The most comprehensive IDE for .NET and C++ developers on Windows for building web, cloud, desktop, mobile apps, services and games.

In contrast, Visual Studio Code is more language agnostic, and extensions are used to support development in specific languages.

> A standalone source code editor that runs on Windows, macOS, and Linux. The top pick for Java and web developers, with tons of extensions to support just about any programming language.

Comment: yeah. seems to be where we are at. I didn't know about the .NET part wrt Visual Studio Professional. Thanks for that heads up

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found you can use Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio 2019 is through an [Anaconda install](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/). Then you can import the related Jupyter modules that come with Anaconda.

[image]

[image]

- Jupyter Notebook isn't available as an extension in [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Installs).
- [Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527522/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio) between Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio Code -- and [a way](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) to help decide which of the two you should use.

Comment: great answer but seems to be low on details. Would you mind elaborating? I've placed a 500 point bounty on the question if that helps.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck I no longer use Visual Studio 2019. I've been using Jupyter with Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Azure Data Studio to use Jupyter notebook in it or Google Colab.

Comment: great idea! But doesn't answer the OP's question