# No intellisense in VS Code C# Debug console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, omnisharp

I'm trying to debug the .net core 6.0 application in VS Code. During the debug session and debugger is paused at breakpoint and when I type object variable in debug console, there is no intellisense which shows the available properties. Is this feature not yet available in VS Code? My visual studio version is  1.67.1 and OmniSharp(C# extension)  version is 1.24.4

Comment: It is not available. Many features you enjoy in Visual Studio for Windows are not available in VS for Mac or VS Code.

Comment: I don't understand why there so many people using vs code!

Comment: @HamedH I used Visual Studio from the first version ever up until 2019!
I switched to VS code in the last 2~3 years, and never looked back!
You have to adapt it to understand why.

Comment: @Nour, I used it recently for "asp.net 6" in medium and big size projects for a month, and switched back to VS just because of the intellisense

Comment: Here I explained it more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73400016/6339469

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience as well, and seems like part of the reason why Microsoft is planning to add a new debugger to the C# experience:

See (long) details here:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5276#issue-1272557442

And my attempt at explaining it here:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5276#issuecomment-1280257922