The code is not compiled in Unity. How to fix it?
When saving/running the script, Unity does not see any changes in the code.
Changes to the code start working only after restarting Unity.
I have not found a solution to my problem. I have to restart UNITY every time so that the changes in the script work.
Previously, I just saved the script, the changes took effect without restarting Unity, immediately after compilation.  Currently, compilation does not occur until Unity is restarted

NB Never use VisualStudio.  Use VSCode with Unity.

Rider IDE one love :D especially with plugins like Heap Allocation Viewer)

Using Rider at the moment aswell, but VisualStudio in the past. Make sure to always have the latest components installed. Also install or update the Visual Studio Editor package inside of Unity.  MS Guide

@Fattie well unity kinda dropped vscode support directly, so not the best advice.

Now, it would be useful to see the settings you have for editing c# files, in that if you found the editor exe and added it manually, it also maybe you have turned off some of the recompiel options to give faster itterations - there are packages that do this but unless you load that package then in every project it means you end up with it not noticing updates

VisualStudio is absolutley great to use with Unity, but make sure you have the packages installed in both VisualSudio and in Unity which let them talk to each other properly.

Guys I think the point is at a minimum, the new user should tell WHICH text editor they are using!  Morion, cool eccentric people use Rider :)

Also if the user is using Mac or PC, totally different.

@BugFinder quite true of course, I'd say it is still the most popular though.  in re the OP here, who has disappeared anyway, it's inconceivable they'd be using a paid product

well studio community is open to people like me who are non commercial, but as you say our OP does seem to have vanished - not uncommon, maybe will come back in 2 weeks

As you say, if you

Type something in to any of the c# scripts
Tap SAVE in the text editor
Tap the usual "Run" button (triangle icon) in Unity

it should run straightaway, showing the changes.
Some possibilities,

Are you using VSCode for text editing?  In the real world it is the only usable option for Unity. (NOT VisualStudio .. VSCode.)

Did you install the necessary plug in for VSCode?  You mention it has previously worked normally, but, you never know.

Did you add some simple log lines in the script, which, you should see on the console. (Maybe your changes just have some bug and you see no change.)

Have you added any extensions or packages lately? They could be the issue.



I strongly disagree that VSCode is the only usable option. I have been using Rider IDE for about five years already. It is the best IDE for using with Unity for now, IMO.

Unity also dropped the package to support it, so, not the best advice

I've used both VisualStudio and Rider with unity professionally for years, they are both totally usable. What do you mean by that?

All of this reminds me of the "Unity Text Editor Wars" from years ago :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301180/294884   A million views!  1000 vote question!  All now irrelevant and water under the bridge ..
