# Fold and unfold code in Visual Studio CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-folding

I can't find out how to fold and unfold code (like javascript functions) in Visual Studio Code.
In Visual Studio the shortcut is "Ctrl + L", but it doesn't work in Visual Studio Code (not the full Visual Studio but the lightweight Code editor).

Everything I searched so far leads me to Visual Studio shortcuts, not VS Code....

Comment: If you hit this answer on google: it's implemented now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30077543/2157581

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supported yet, but under review...

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752321-add-code-folding-support

I miss it too.