# Visual studio code - keyboard shortcuts - expand/collapse all

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to find the equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> in Intellij that collapses/expands all functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I collapse sections of code in Visual Studio Code for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows)

Answer (score 512, accepted):

Here it is.

```
Ctrl+Shift+[    Fold (collapse) region  editor.fold
Ctrl+Shift+]    Unfold (uncollapse) region  editor.unfold
Ctrl+K Ctrl+[   Fold (collapse) all subregions  editor.foldRecursively
Ctrl+K Ctrl+]   Unfold (uncollapse) all subregions  editor.unfoldRecursively
Ctrl+K Ctrl+0   Fold (collapse) all regions editor.foldAll
Ctrl+K Ctrl+J   Unfold (uncollapse) all regions
```

Take Look at Visual studio Code [Keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings) section at this link.

Also Platform specific Key board shortcuts available in pdf.here is the links

[Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf),[MAC](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf),[Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)

Comment: This may have a conflict with the Vim plugin.  Mentioning in case folks come here and scratch their head why it seems not to work.  The Vim plugin is extremely bad about Ctrl-key sequences and MSoft could care less.

Comment: Ctrl + K Ctrl + 3

Comment: Nice, and for Mac users, all same, just in place of `Ctrl` use `⌘ (Command)`

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to make Ctrl+K+zero and Ctrl+K+J a pair of commonly used key bindings.   Very wise to make them completely forgettable and bizarre.  Well done Microsoft.  Looking forward to not being able to install Windows 11.

Answer (score 47):

You can set custom values for that.

1. Open the Command Palette (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> on Mac)
2. Search `Open Keyboard Shortcuts`
3. Then search for `collapse`
4. Finally click the <kbd>+</kbd> sign near the `Collapse All` and `Collapse Folders in Explorer` options and set the shortcuts like I did

[image: keyboard vscode collapse all shortcuts]

Or you can open `keybindings.json` file and add this to the main array.

```
 ,
  {
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+s",
    "command": "search.action.collapseSearchResults"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+e",
    "command": "workbench.files.action.collapseExplorerFolders"
  }
```

Answer (score 32):

Go to ***File --> Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts*** (or Ctrl+K Ctrl+S)

Search for the word ***fold all***

The ones you need are:

- Fold All
- Unfold All

Set your custom keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 21):

One simple way I use is:

1. Launch command pallete with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for `Collapse Folders in Explorer`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can also define a custom shortcut for this command in settings.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, a recent update has made all of my folders expand when I first open VS Code, which is less than ideal. This makes it easy to close them all.

Comment: what about expand. Apparently for explorer, the feature is no more there.

Answer (score 5):

Go to 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and type in search input: "fold all regions". You see fold/unfold (expand/collapse) commands and shortcuts. Use or change them.