# Collapse all methods in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

In Visual Studio Professional, we have a shortcut key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>O</kbd> to collapse all methods and properties in a class. How can I do a similar thing in Visual Studio Code?

I know there are shortcut keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, but this does not meet the needs.

Is it possible to get the Visual Studio Professional-like behaviour in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: see this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows/30077543#30077543

Comment: You can also press F1 whilst editing, and in the search bar, type fold or unfold and you will see clickable options to do everything below and more, it also shows the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: cmd + shift + p (then search for "fold" to find it or even select it)

Comment: For those having problems with any of the CTRL-shortcuts: check your active addons. I had a vim-addon installed which seemed to block those shortcuts.

Comment: For (currently) most famous vim-addon Vim (`vscodevim`) you may add this to your `settings.json`: `"vim.handleKeys": { "<C-k>": false }`

Answer (score 1769):

- Fold All:

  - Windows and Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`0`</kbd> **(ZERO)**
  - Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`0`</kbd>
- Unfold All:

  - Windows and Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
  - Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

To see all available shortcuts in the editor:

- Windows and Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts]

All shortcuts kept up to date by the Visual Studio Code  team: [Visual Studio Code Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

Comment: Thanks with Cmd+k Cmd+S to open the short key setting. It's really helpful.

Comment: For those confused like I was, that's a ZERO, not an o.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not apply to current versions like 1.41+ (or even lower versions). Anyway - the posted picture still seems to be correct, because you have to Press&Hold Ctrl. then press K, release Ctrl, press&hold it again, and then press one of the other keys like O, 1, 2 and so on! Pressing Ctrl.+K, releasing everything and then pressing S for example does "Save all". The releasing and pressing of Ctrl. again is important here and makes the difference! See some answer below...

Comment: seems like shortcuts made to `longcuts`. :).

Comment: @Satria Your statement that [control + k, 1] and [control + k, control + 1] are two different shortcuts is correct and usefully points out that this answer isn't as clear as it should be.  However, your statement that you need to release and re-press control in between the k and the 1 to activate the latter shortcut is wrong.  You can simply hold control while you press and release k and then press and release 1 to activate the shortcut [control + k, control + 1].  Just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: @MarredCheese Thanks for your info. Just tried it, you are right. No need to release CTRL in between K and 1. At least now, in version 1.51.1. Maybe I simply misunderstood the answer those days. The answer in its current state is fine. It's [CTRL+K+S], not [CTRL+K, S]

Comment: PS: The `0` button needs to be the one above the alphabets. Num-pad `0` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For those that are confused, VS Code handles listening to a first keystroke then a second one. 

To Fold all regions, you would press on Ctrl+K then on Ctrl+0
You would need to release Ctrl between the two presses.
(You actually can notice that VS code prompts a message in its Blue bar status stating that it's "waiting for a second key or chord")

Comment: Just for added clarity, I had mistakenly thought Ctrl K + Ctrl # would unfold those items that are not folded by the particular number.  For instance, I had already folded all levels using Ctrl K + Ctrl 0 and then hit Ctrl K + Ctrl 2. I couldn't figure out why nothing was happening, assuming it would unfold to level 2.  However, it simply folds everything to the level set, regardless of it's previous state. So if you have some portions folded that you would like unfolded it might be best to unfold everything using Ctrl K + Ctrl J and then fold to your desired level.

Comment: vscode is actually too good

Comment: This might not work if you imported Sublime shortcuts (at least it did not work for me). If so you can `⌘+shift+p` and type `fold all` as mentioned by reply bellow

Answer (score 408):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>: fold all levels (namespace, class, method, and block)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>: namespace / @Component(For Angular)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>: class / methods
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>: methods / blocks
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>: blocks / inner blocks
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>: current cursor block
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>: UnFold

#### [From Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding)

[image]

Comment: btw, for those of us on OSX, use cmd in place of ctrl

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as "fold all" is cleary not the same as "collapse all methods and properties", this anwers the question perfectly

Comment: Sounds like `Ctrl + K + 3` doesn't work fine in Java, folds a for loop in a method instead of folding the method itself. Tried multiple times.

Comment: That's incorrect, namespaces, classes,  methods, etc. do not necessarily sit at levels 1, 2, 3, etc. It just deals with folding/unfolding whatever is at these levels.

Answer (score 250):

Like this ? (Visual Studio Code version 0.10.11)

Fold All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)

Unfold All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

Fold Level n (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

Comment: Unfortunately no. This one collapses everything, including the class itself, methods,if-else conditions and loops inside the methods. Where as in VS professional it just collapses methods. When we open a method it opens up fully.

Comment: Added a 'fold level' shortcut. Maybe it's what you're looking for ?

Comment: @eadam In a typescript file, `Ctrl + K, 2` does exactly that for me.

Comment: This answer is both concise and also completely correct/clear.  Most others, including the accepted answer, fail to resolve the ambiguity between the shortcuts [control + k, 0] and [control + k, control + 0].

Comment: ctrl+n is the shortcut. edit the answer making it [n]. "Fold Level n (Ctrl+K Ctrl+[ n ] )". or tell there that N=any number

Comment: For dummies => press `Ctrl+K` then take your hand off the keys and press `Ctrl+0` to fold  all

Comment: This is not working with version 1.68.1

Comment: This work in version 1.71

Comment: ctrl + k, 0     ==0(zero)

Answer (score 137):

The beauty of Visual Studio Code is

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Hit it and search anything you want.

In your case, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type *fold all*.

Comment: Cmd + Shift + p for Mac users.

Comment: best answer for me!

Comment: This is the best approach to be used for visual studio folding.

Comment: Best answer for me too. I prefer using the F1 key though.

Comment: There are some things I still use key combinations for, but getting used to Cmd + P and Cmd + Shift + P is by far the best that ever happened to my VSCode workflow.

Comment: best answer!!!!

Comment: Not the best answer for me, if you're used to the word "collapse" then you won't find it in that search.

Comment: This solves issue of colliding shortcuts for me, thank you!

Answer (score 37):

### Mac Users

**Fold Commands**

[image]

**Unfold commands**
[image]

Comment: For dummies => press `⌘+K` then take your hand off the keys and press `⌘+0` to fold all –

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> will do close to what you want.

The first command collapses level 1 (usually classes), and the second command collapses level 2 (usually methods).

You might even find it useful to skip the first command.

Comment: What do you mean by *"will do close to what you want."* (it seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - In English, this construct basically resolves to "[this suggestion] will [accomplish something similar to] what you want [to accomplish]." 
He's saying the suggestion will do (accomplish) close to (similar to) what the OP wants (the thing he wants to do).

Comment: Correct and precise answer for the current version 1.42.1, because it helps to understand, that you have to release Ctrl. and press&hold it again before each of the K and 1 keys!

Comment: thx, `Ctrl`+`K`, `Ctrl`+`2` do the job in May, 2020

Comment: If its already fully collapsed, first do `Ctrl`+`K`,`Ctrl`+`J` to "expand all". THEN do one of the mentioned commands, to expand just the level(s) you want. Otherwise, you may find that the contents of each method are collapsed at the block level, requiring unfolding each block.

Answer (score 25):

*Collapse All* is *Fold All* in Visual Studio Code.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for *All Settings*. Assign a key which you want for 
*Fold All*. By default it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: This does not bring value as this is already discussed in other upvoted answers.

Comment: @Nilambar I disagree. This is the only answer that helped me change the keybind quickly.

Answer (score 24):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to fold all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to unfold all.

Comment: @SunilGarg You can use Ctrl + Shift + [ to fold single code block and Ctrl + Shift + ] to unfold

Comment: Use Ctrl + K + / to old all comments multiple lines.

Answer (score 12):

You should add user settings:

```
{
    "editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
    "editor.folding": true,
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation", 
}
```

Comment: I've tried messing with this several times. Unsure how these settings help. I notice more - symbol buttons, but that's it. This doesn't seems to accomplish closing or opening "all" blocks.

Comment: @Urasquirrel I think the first line just shows all those icons instead of only showing them when you hover over the thin space near line numbers. the indentation foldingStrategy seems to be the default, as I haven't changed that myself, so you didn't notice anything. Not sure what folding does.

Comment: @JakeT. Thanks! That makes more sense. I kinda figured out the first one. I wish there was a way to auto fold all blocks or specific types of code when you open the files. For example typescript interfaces at the top of files are annoying as hell. When I hover an interface I can see it's definition so I don't need them open and taking up real estate.

Comment: @Urasquirrel No problem. I don't know if getting fine grained on which types to open/close is feasible, but the answer above ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/43710782/4544328 ) will show you how to close all, and then you could use the command to open an individual block as needed while editing code. It's the best low-effort solution available that I've found.

Answer (score 1):

I recently made an extension for collapsing C# code to definitions since I was also missing that feature from Visual Studio. Just look for "Fold to Definitions" and you should find it, or just follow [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=argiolasriccardo90.fold-to-definitions).

The repository is public, so you can easily inspect the `extension.ts` file and adapt it to other languages. It is nowhere near perfect, but it does the job. It uses regular expressions to find methods, properties, and classes, and then moves the selection to those lines and executes a fold command.

Answer (score -3):

To collapse methods in the Visual Studio Code editor:

1. Right-click anywhere in document and select "format document" option.
2. Then hover next to number lines and you will see the (-) sign for collapsing method.

NB.: As per the Visual Studio Code documentation, a folding region starts when a line has a smaller indent than one or more following lines, and ends when there is a line with the same or smaller indent.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work more intelligently. When you have TypeScript, the { } symbols don't just signify functions/methods. Often it relates to Objects, if/else statements too - and suddenly all that is being collapsed too.

Comment: OP and the people coming to this question are looking for shortcuts to do what you described. Manually collapsing every code blocks is a tedious task.