# How to I collapse all sections of code with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I believe this is a pretty straight forward question. In Visual Studio 2015, Ctr+M+O collapsed all sections. I learned this trick from here: [Visual Studio - Command to collapse all sections of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code) Unfortunately, his does not work in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapse all methods in Visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660670/collapse-all-methods-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @jonvw Completely different question. This is about ALL. People see the other Q (I know I did) "collapse all methods" and focus in the "collapse all" part. The "methods" is confusing -- who would want that, and wouldn't it be called "collapse ONLY methods"? But that oddly-phrased Q comes up first in searches.

Answer (score 9):

Use Ctrl + M + A to collapse all, but first you need to enable it through Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Outlining > Tick Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions.

Comment: It is Ctrl+M+O to Collapse all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660670/collapse-all-methods-in-visual-studio-code?rq=1

Comment: @AkshayAnand Ctrl+M+A will collapse up to the namespace, so my answer is technically right.