# Vistual Studio 2019: Shortcut key to collapse this method only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

How can I collapse only current method which cursor is currently located in its block inside VS2019(Windows)?

I know about `Ctrl+M,Ctrl+O` but I want shortcut for to collapse only one method not more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collapse all methods in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660670/collapse-all-methods-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Herohtar I could not find the correct shortcut in documentaions

Comment: In addition to that document, a Google search for [exactly what you want to do](https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+Studio+2019+collapse+current+method) returns [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/outlining?view=vs-2019) which gives the correct answer in the third sentence on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please use below shortcut to collapse one method
<kbd>CTL+M+M</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ctrl+M+M, resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTL+M+M</kbd> collapses only the method that your cursor is blinking on. 
[This other thread has more information on Visual Studio shortcuts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660670/collapse-all-methods-in-visual-studio-code?rq=1)

Answer (score -2):

you can use **ctrl + shift + [**, this might work

Comment: I saw it in other questions but I don't know why this one do nothing in my IDE

Comment: try ctrl + m and ctrl + o