# VS Code/JS/TS: fold the class methods only

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, is there a way to fold/unfold only the class methods found in the file?

I'm aware of [Collapse all methods in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660670/collapse-all-methods-in-visual-studio-code) but Ctrl + K + 2, or 3 only deal with the code block level and not the semantics of whether it's a method or not.

Comment: not sure if there's an option for just classes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/outlining?view=vs-2022

Comment: I'm asking about VS Code actually, not VS.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you know it... Just found an extension that does exactly that. Fold To Definitions by Zeev Rotshtein

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zeevro.fold-to-definitions