# Fold HTML tag attributes feature similar to Sublime Text

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

One feature I've found really useful in Sublime Text is the ability to [fold HTML tag attributes](http://sublimetexttips.com/quick-tip-fold-html-tag-attributes-while-editing-cluttered-docs/). Is there a way to do this with VSCode that I'm missing?

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. Also, it seems the extension API currently doesn't have a way of hiding characters, see [this open feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13632) (except for a hack mentioned by the second comment).

Extensions also can't customize the built-in folding yet, see [#3422](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3422).

Answer (score -1):

To fold individual attributes just move your mouse pointer to the left of the editor, in the empty space on the right of the line numbers. Small `-` icons will appear. Click on the ones you want to fold items.

Keyboard shortcut is `CTRL+SHIFT+]`.

You can get the full list of key bindings there: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: That will fold tag _children_ but not tag attributes.