# How to fold/expand all functions in a selection in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, selection, expand

Is there a way to fold/expand a large selection of functions(javascript code) in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> will fold all:

[image: all folded]

and

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> will unfold all

But it works on the whole file, not on a selection.
You can also fold only a certailn level with the commands

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
...
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>
for level 1 ... 9

You find these shortcuts in the keyboard shortcuts:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows.