# How to move to lines with the same indentation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I navigate to next and previous lines with same Indentation in Visual Studio Code?

For Eg:

```
First line
    Second line
    Third line
        Fourth line
        Fifth line
    Sixth line
Seventh line
```

So that if I place the cursor on Third line I can navigate to Second or Sixth line. All on the same level of indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of trough a native shortcut.

You would need to fold the level 2, hiding lines 3, 4 and 5, in order to be able to go from line two (sill visible), to line 6 still visible.

For folding, see "[How do I collapse sections of code in Visual Studio Code for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30067767/6309)".

Comment: This is how I am working currently.The problem is that when I'm editing the file I paste very large portions of text to a lower level. I paste it already indented, thanks to [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rubymaniac.vscode-paste-and-indent). My goal is to have a way to navigate back to the previous line of the same indentation level after pasting these texts, so that I can fold the just pasted text.