# VS Code Folding Based on Brackets - Not Indentation

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, folding

Hello Stackoverflow community,

This is my first post here. I am using VS Code and am currently looking for a way to enable method and function folding by default like the feature available in PHPStorm. I looked around here and found some posts showing that you can fold all of the code or indentation levels as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30077543/10713286
However, I am looking for a way to fold functions and methods using matching brackets as the folding method rather than indentation or use of `//#region` and `//#endregion`. Ideally, this could be the default and I could unfold the code as needed. PHPStorm does this beautifully and leaves the documentation method and function comments unfolded as an option. I am thinking this may need to be done by writing an extension. I am having trouble finding a way to do this though. I pulled the VS Code git repo and ran some grep searches to find that the folding method (for php) is set in `vscode/extensions/php/package.nls.json:3`. There are `#region` and `#endregion` settings in `vscode/extensions/php/snippets/php.snippets.json` on lines 243 and 250. The problem is that the folding is set with regex and I can't find a way to match brackets using regex alone.

This is an important feature for me because I am learning a new code base and having function/method folding really improves readability of large files. I can quickly scan for what I need and expand as needed. VS Code tries to do this, but if there are any lines intentionally outdented in a function, to make a comment more obvious for example, VS Code stops folding there rather than going to the end of the function. Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!!

tldr; I need to find a way to fold code based on matching brackets rather than indentation in VS Code.

Answer (score 4):

VS Code has two ways of handling folding for a language:

- Indentation based (plus basic `#region` support). This works out of the box for many languages but is quite simple. It only looks at indentation to determine how code should be folded
- [Syntax aware code folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_syntax-aware-folding). This must be implemented per language. VS Code ships with syntax aware folding for javascript, typescript, html, css, json, and markdown. Support for other languages can be provided by extensions

I am not aware of any existing extensions that implement syntax aware folding for php. If you would like implement it yourself, take a look at the [folding provider api](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_folding-provider-api)