# How to fold big json arrays in visual studio code editor in mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

I read this answer ([How do I collapse sections of code in Visual Studio Code for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows)) and tried changing settings, extensions, etc... I still had to go back to sublime to do basic code folding. I'm on a mac. Visual studio code Version 1.30.2 (1.30.2).

Visual studio code (not working)

[image]

Sublime (working)

[image]

How do I get those little collapse buttons to show in visual studio code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show code folding controls you need to hover between the line numbers and code.  [image: VS Code folding controls]

Comment: I must have some extension blocking that, I don't get that behavior.

Comment: @KylePennell line numbers shown in VS Code are not the same, but it looks like it's the same file. Is this a bug or it's just a part code pasted?

Comment: yeah, I'm just not seeing those upon hovering...good to know they should be there though

Comment: some sort of plugin was messing with it. Disabled a bunch and it's all good now

Answer (score 3):

For me, it wasn't because of an extension but because of this setting:

```
"editor.folding": false,
```

Commenting it out has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tokenization, wrapping and folding is turned off for large files in order to reduce memory usage and avoid freezing or crashing. Put this into `settings.json` to enable this feature:

```json
"editor.foldingMaximumRegions": 500000, // defaults to 5000, adjust to your needs
"editor.largeFileOptimizations": false
```