# VSCode how to stop automatic expanding of collapsed code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I keep running into an issue with VSCode where collapsed code expands when I start typing certain characters (i.e. "(", "{", "/*"). With very large code files, this is taking up a lot of time trying to collapse code again, when I am just trying to code new functions, comment out things, etc.

Anyone know how to stop this? I've looked into settings and can't see any that control this behavior. Basically, I just wanna type code like it was 2000!

Cheers,
Guy with long code files wasting minutes recollapsing code

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

This is not configurable and sounds unexpected. Please file [a bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).

[This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83353) already tracks something similar

Comment: 3 years and still happening ... microsoft ...

Comment: Yes, still happening and still frustrating. Why not just close braces only on user events?