# How do I stop vscode from expanding of collapsed codes on its own?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

windows 10 19044.1706

vscode 1.67.2

python 3.10.2 (venv)

---

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783521/vscode-how-to-stop-automatic-expanding-of-collapsed-code) post

I'm still looking for fix settings

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode how to stop automatic expanding of collapsed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783521/vscode-how-to-stop-automatic-expanding-of-collapsed-code)

Comment: I know you wrote you already read that question, but the fact that you don't like the answer is not a valid reason to ask the same question again. As far as I can tell, it's an exact duplicate. If you're asking for something different, please clarify how this question is different than the other one.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing your problem is that under some operations, VS Code automatically expands your already collapsed code.

As far as the picture you show, you remove the closing bracket after method `b`, then vscode's intellisense cannot get the end of method `b`. So that it includes both methods `c` and `d` after method `b`. Then methods `a`, `b`, `c` become a whole when folded.

Hope it helps with your question.