# Make code foldable at custom locations using specific comments in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am working with *Visual Studio Code* to create react native apps. To get a better overview of my code, I would like to collapse specific code blocks. But I want to be able to decide where and what to collapse. For this, it would be really nice if a custom comment combination would trigger a folding button on the sidebar.

For example, if I write `//-` instead of only `//` at the beginning of a line it should add a collapse button on that line. Is this (or something similar) possible in *Visual Studio Code*?

Answer (score 0):

Look at code folding by regions.  See [How do I collapse sections of code in Visual Studio Code for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows/46597272#46597272).

But I don't think you can alter the region syntax to whatever you want, it is defined by the language configuration.

Try `// #region` and `// #endregion` for javascript react. (or `//#region` and `//#endregion`)