# Visual Studio "Create Collapsible Region (Ctrl+M+H)" Equivalent in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio there is a user defined collapsible region creation shortcut Ctrl+M+H. I really love this shortcut.

I am aware of [this question regarding foldings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows). However I really wish there was a way to collapse / fold the selected text section of the code in VS Code. Is there any way of doing this?

EDIT:

I see the [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18805) on VSCode.

Comment: Have a look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! This is definitely nice. I will use it! Ultimately though, I wish they would have the shortcut ported.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71991706/836330 for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

To fold selected text, use this command, new as of Insiders v1.70:

```
Create Manual Folding Range from Selection
editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection
```

There is also this related command:

```
Fold All Regions Except Selected
editor.foldAllExcept
```

Comment: niiiice cannot wait to try it out!