# How to group a section of code into a collapsible segment in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have about 50 lines of C code that I want to collapse. It's at the top-level, containing globals, typedefs, defines, etc. The only way I've figured out how to do this is by making a fake function, for example:

[image]

Is there another way to do this in VS Code?

Comment: Can't speak for VS Code but, in Visual Studio (proper), you can use `#ifndef unique_daft_token` and `#endif` lines to form collapsible sections.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks -- what's `unique_daft_token` ?

Comment: Anything you want it to be. Doesn't have to be daft and probably doesn't have to be unique. Something that is meaningful, though. `#ifndef code_for_minimizing_x`, for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597272/836330 Make your regions for folding - built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Region folding plugin will do what you want https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder