# Set VS Code Default to Collapse

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've checked the settings, and just want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

Is there a way to have VS Code collapse your code by default?

I'm referring to when you open a file with nested div's etc.

Can you have them automatically collapse down to enable quicker scrolling through the file?

Thank you!

Comment: This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Fold extension to collapse all the idented code when open your files.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felicio.vscode-fold

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks Tiago!