# Wrap off just some markdown blocks

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Right now, when writing markdown in visual studio I have the configuration to wrap words according to the view port, and this is just fine, but sometimes I have to insert some base64 codes that have more than 200000 characters.

The base64 lines fill pages and pages with "useless" information.

[image: Sample with base 64 with wrap on]

Ideally, I want to achieve something similar to this in an automatic way or something close to it:

[image]

As you can see, the objective is to have "wrap on" for the information and the "wrap off" for the base 64 information.

---

So the point is to understand if there is a way to wrap off just some blocks and keep the wrap on viewport for the rest of the information

I thought in some workarounds

- Wrap off lines starting with XXXXX ( in this case wrap off lines that start with:

  ![ ](
- Wrap off just just selected lines using some specific plugin (tried the rewrap plugin)
- Mess with the editor properties in settings json to wrap on lines with length 0 till 100 (for example)

but enable to get some success with it.

Right now, I have a pretty straight configurations in my settings.json (nothing is overriding the markdown section)

```
"[markdown]": {        
        "editor.wordWrap": "on",
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "darkriszty.markdown-table-prettify",
    },
```

Let me know if someone had the same problem and managed to workaround this situation

Feel free to ask for further information

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can add a feature request for the markdown extension to add folding regions to very long lines or lines starting with a regex, now only header lines mark folding regions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you wrap it in
`<div> ... </div>`, since it does not have any effect on your document, and then *fold* it. You can fold the text in VSCode with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
or by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and typing `fold`, selecting it while having your line cursor inside the div.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30077543/6942707) a very nice answer as well.

Comment: As @rioV8 suggested, adding a header (any line starting with `#`) on the line above your long text will also allow you to collapse it.

Comment: yes, it is a nice trick and do the workaround. Right now i'm using the # to collapse the lines. Great!
Thanks!