# How to hide <summary> in [metadata] when press F12 (Go to definition) in visual studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Could you please help me to hide the summary comments when I press F12 (Go to definition) in Visual Studio Code? I do not want to see summary comments as they are too long.

Could you please help me see only declarations of classes, methods, e.g. but not summary comments? There is the screen when I press F12 on int.

[image: code sample]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following keyboard shortcut:

`Ctrl + M + O`

If you want to expand again you can use `Ctrl + M + L`

Alternatively you can try: Edit > Outlining > Collapse to Definitions
[image]

You can check for more similar shortcuts here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I do not have "Outlining" popup in Visual studio code, also, unfortunately, Ctrl+M+O does not work for me. I checked shortcuts in File=>Preferencies=>Keyboard Shortcuts, I do not have this shortcut

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, I just saw that you are using visual studio code, not visual studio.
Check this post -> might help you. From what I read it looks like the shortcut is `Ctrl + K + 0`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows

Comment: I have this shortcut for folding. When I press it, nothing happens. Folding is not what I need, I want completely do not to see comments in metadata, only declarations of classes, methods, properties, e.g

Answer (score 2):

The summary comments are helpful metadata in the assembly. If you open it in Visual Studio 2019/2017 etc, it is feasible to collapse them.

[image]

However, it seems impossilbe to collapse the summary to definitions in VS code. I tried it in vain before long.

Because the summaries are embeded in the assembly(the *.dll file), it is impossible to removed them. Even it is open via F12, it is readonly.

Comment: Thank. Does it mean that I cannot nor collapse nor "completely hide" them in visual studio code?

Comment: From my point of view, it is not doable to collapse or hide them in VS code.

Comment: @YuliiaSerhiienko BTW, if you make it in VS code sometime, can you pls inform me?