# How to disable folding comments in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I press the hotkey `CTRL` `M` `O` it does fold everything, is possible to don't fold comments?

Currently using `Visual Studio` with `c++`.

Comment: I click on the `[-]` button in the left gutter.

Comment: @Eljay i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396809/4641116 (although that's for VSCode, Visual Studio has the same feature).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, in Visual Studio for C++ projects.

You can check here: Outlining, there lists the all optional options for “collapse” and “expand”. Normally, there are five commands for “collapse” and “expand”:

1). Toggle [Outlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/outlining?view=vs-2019) Expansion   Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M

2). Toggle All Outlining                Ctrl+M, Ctrl+L

3). Stop Outlining                         Ctrl+M, Ctrl+P

4). Stop Hiding Current               Ctrl+M, Ctrl+U

5). Collapse to Definitions          Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O

but none of them meet your requirements, you can only expand(disable folding comments) them one by one.

You can [suggest this feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion) to VS Product Team on Microsoft Developer Community.